# TinyMCE & JustBoil.ME Image Uploader

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce, justboil.me

I am trying to use the jbimages plugin for tinymce, and its loading and okay except that when the script tries to upload images, I get the following error:

Disallowed Key Characters.

What is that, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by remarking

```
function _clean_input_keys($str)
    {
        if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
        {
            //REMARK THIS
            //exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
        }
        // Clean UTF-8 if supported
        if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE)
        {
            $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
        }
        return $str;
    }
```

in

```
jbimages/ci/system/core/input.php
```